# How to correctly catch two columns with repeated value from a txt file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get two columns with repeated value from a text file. This text file has a thousand information using the follow structure:

```
ip,country,city,latitude,longitude
```

And this a real example:

```
179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951
177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568
.
.
.
to the end
```

I wanna catch "-23.3939", "-46.4951" and "-9.5934", "-35.7568" to compare if the two coordinates are the same and put the whole line in another text file. So I found something here in Stackoverflow and it works only if I use the latitude, but I want to get and compare latitude and longitude (original code):

```
entries = []
duplicate_entries = []
with open('in.txt', 'r') as my_file:
for line in my_file:
    columns = line.strip().split(',')
    if columns[2] not in entries:
        entries.append(columns[2])
    else:
        duplicate_entries.append(columns[2]) 

if len(duplicate_entries) > 0:
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    with open('in.txt', 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            columns = line.strip().split(',')
            if columns[2] in duplicate_entries:
                print line.strip()
                out_file.write(line)
else:
print "No repetitions"
```

To do what I wanted, I tried this:

```
entries = []
duplicate_entries = []
with open('/home/usr/python-programming/ip-infos', 'r') as arq:
for line in arq:
    columns = line.strip().split(',')
    if columns[3] and columns[4] not in entries:
        entries.append(columns[3])
        entries.append(columns[4])
    else:
        duplicate_entries.append(columns[3])
        duplicate_entries.append(columns[4])
arq.close()

if len(duplicate_entries) > 0:
with open('/home/usr/python-programming/suspects', 'w') as 
out_file:
    with open('/home/usr/python-programming/ip-infos', 'r') as 
arq:
        for line in arq:
            columns = line.strip().split(',')
            if columns[3] and columns[4] in duplicate_entries:
                print line.strip()
                out_file.write(line)
        out_file.close()
        arq.close()
else:
print "No repetitions"
```

So, here is the output if I manipulate the text file:

```
179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951
177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568

>output: "No repetitions" and nothing is writed to the out_file(correct)

179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951
177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-23.3939,-46.4951

>output: 179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951
         177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-23.3939,-46.4951
         (and this two lines appear in the out_file (correct))
```

But if I do this:

```
 179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3938,-46.4951
 177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-23.3939,-46.4951

 >output: 179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3938,-46.4951
          177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-23.3939,-46.4951
          (and this two lines appear in the out_file (incorrect))
```

"-23.3938" is different from "-23.3939" even if longitude is equal. So it shouldn't appear in the out_file and show "No repetitions" in the terminal. I've tried for many hours, but I'm still learning and I don't know to do that. Could somebody help me?

Comment: So you want to check every set of two sequential lines, and compare their lng and lat?

Comment: No, just the column[3] (latitude) and column[4] (longitude) from all lines. But now I'm making some changes in the code after the answer from 'kdheepak'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
if columns[3] and columns[4] not in entries:
```

It really should be the following:

```
if (columns[3] in entries) and (columns[4] in entries):
```

You will also need to make the same change for the `if` condition using `duplicate_entries`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hours ago I tried it just changing the 'duplicate_entries' condition but I didn't try the same change in both conditions, now it works perfeclty. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put the input from your file into a dictionary.
in that way you will be able to get duplicate at once

```
elements = ['179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951',
'177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568',
'179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951',
'177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568',
'179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951']

uniques = {}
for line in elements:
    ip, country, city, lat, long = line.strip().split(',')
    uniques.setdefault((lat, long), []).append(line)




uniques = {('-23.3939', '-46.4951'): ['179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São 
Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951', '179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São 
Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951', '179.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,São 
Paulo,-23.3939,-46.4951'],
('-9.5934', '-35.7568'): 
['177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568',
'177.xxx.xxx.xxx,Brazil,Maceió,-9.5934,-35.7568']}
```

At this moment you will have key (lat, long) and values is a list with all lines with the same coordinates

```
with open('duplicate.txt', 'w') as duplicate:
    for coord, cities in uniques.items():
        if len(cities) == 1:
            continue
        duplicate.write('\n'.join(cities))
```

defaultdict from collections can be used in place of setdefault(k, [])